# Android toolchain - develop for Android devices

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, sdk

I have no idea what is the problem.. My system environment variables screenshots are here..

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

```
X No valid Android SDK platforms found in C:\Users\Pubudu Arosha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms. Directory was empty.
```

[image]
[image]
[image]